# Is it correct to say "Please fix the errors"

Tags: articles

Is it correct to add "the" before errors if these errors are listed right above the message? Or should I just write "Please fix errors above" or just "Please fix errors"?

E.g.

> - error1: error1 text
> - error2: error2 text
> - error3: error3 text
>
> Please fix **the** errors ....

Comment: This example is typical of techie talk, notes to staff, shorthand instructions. Holding it to the standards of flawless English is a bit unfair. Doesn't jargon get a pass if understood by those involved? Ping me if you have the bandwidth.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, you cannot omit the article *the*. If you do, it becomes ungrammatical in English. You cannot say this:

1. Please fix errors above. ❌

But you can say these:

2. Please fix **the** errors above. ✅
3. Please fix **any** errors above. ✅

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should. Using "the" in the sentence refers to just these errors. It is vital that you do so. It would be better if you were to say "these errors" so as to be specific about them.

Comment: *Please fix errors above* is not grammatical without any determiner. Are you alleging that it actually **is** grammatical?

Comment: @tchrist I do not think that was the OP's question. You may may be right that it is not correct.